# Azure Bot Authorization within Azure Web App

Tags: azure-active-directory, teams-toolkit

I am creating a Microsoft Teams Application using TeamsFX 5.0.

I initially created an app using a tab template. I then integrated the Notification bot to this. This web app has a page called "Notification" where you can click a button which will hit a controller end point (in this case the default template https://websitename.azurewebsites.net/api/notification)

My issue is that it returns a **401 unauthorized**:
[image]

Now the reason this is happening is because in Azure my web app has auth on it which ensures they are a Microsoft tenant user.
[image]

When I go to this URL I'm told to sign in, and I can login fine and that's why I can access the web app. I've made this work by adding a redirect URI in the app registration:
[image]

And I've also allowed a user through the Enterprise Application:
[image]

The issue is I'm unsure on how to allow my Azure Bot to call this /api/messages endpoint to post a notification that is received in teams. **If I remove the auth from web app it works fine**  but I'm unsure on what steps to take here. I have an app registration for the bot too but don't know what permissions need placing where. So just to clarify I have the code I need to send a notification because it works without authentication. But since the web app has auth on it, how will the azure bot get past this?

Not sure if appsettings.json is relevant too but:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "BOT_ID": "ID HERE",
  "BOT_PASSWORD": "PW HERE",
  "TeamsFx": {
    "Authentication": {
      "ClientId": "ID HERE",
      "ClientSecret": "SECRET HERE",
      "InitiateLoginEndpoint": "https://websitename.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback",
      "OAuthAuthority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The request to `api/messages` endpoint is blocked by Azure App Service, not your app code. As far as I know, there's no way to disable Azure App Service's authentication for a specific endpoint. So you may need to turn off the Azure App Service's authentication feature and use some library like `Microsoft.Identity.Web` to authenticate the users in your app code. In this way, you should be able to disable auth for `api/messages` in your code.

You can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-web-app-aspnet-core-sign-in for how to add authentication to your app.